# pandoc not found, long_description is bad, don't upload this to PyPI

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I'm Installing Pyspark in EC2 Linux 2.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pyspark
```

Not able to install and giving an error.

Error Stack :

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 416, in scan_module
    code = marshal.load(f)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)


!!! pandoc not found, long_description is bad, don't upload this to PyPI !!!
```

I tried `sudo yum install pandoc` and `pip install pandoc`. Nothing works.

Thank you.

Comment: did you add the path to `pandoc` to the PATH env variable?

Comment: I have added path /usr/bin/pandoc. Same issue

Comment: looks like corrupt `pyc` files. delete them and try again

Answer (score 2):

This is worked for me.

```
pip install pypandoc
```